# Cropping image according to coordinates (with scaling factor in mind)

Tags: python, numpy, python-3.7, opencv

I have a simple image file as below, where I have defined a set of coordinates, I want to crop.

The cropping selection is happening on the **frontend**, which means that the image that the user is seeing, is scaled down to fit the user's screen. Below is the information of the image:

```
imageWidth: 965
imageHeight: 1365.46875
```

Based on above width and height, the coordinates of the box you see in the image, is:

```
"x":405.5,
"y":130,
"height":36
"width":129
```

(All numbers are in pixels)

[image: Image I want to crop]

On my backend, in my Python code, I want to make sure that I crop the same as the users are seeing. So I figured, I would have to calculate the x,y scaling factor:

```py
import numpy as np
import cv2

#Open the original image and get widht/height
image = cv2.imread(image_file)
height, width = image.shape[0:2]
```

The original image's height and width is: `H: 3508, W: 2479`

I then calculate the scaling factors:

```py
# Set scaling factors
scalingFactorX = width / imageWidth
scalingFactorY = height / imageHeight
```

Which equals: `Scaling X: 2.5689119170984456, Scaling Y: 2.569081130564138`

After calculating the scaling factors, I convert the original coordinates to scale accordingly:

```py
crop_x = scalingFactorX * box['x']
crop_y = scalingFactorY * box['y']
crop_w = scalingFactorX * box['width']
crop_h = scalingFactorY * box['height']
```

And then finally, I crop the image and save it:

```
crop = image[int(crop_y):int(crop_y)+int(crop_h),
             int(crop_x): int(crop_x) + int(crop_w)]
cv2.imwrite("cropped_image.png", crop)
```

However, the cropped area is **not** correct. It's simply a blank image (I guess the coordinates are way off, which means it ultimately crops another part of the page):

The result is a 331 x 92 pixel blank image.

I am not sure what I am doing wrong?

## Edit:

The original image can be found [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TiIqj.jpg).

Comment: @martineau this is the converted coordinates (`crop = `): `333:425, 1041:1372` - I am not quite sure how I can check these coordinates again the original picture, to see, visually, if I am way off?

Comment: Do the math by hand — that doesn't seem like it would be too difficult — and compare that to what you're actually getting.

Comment: I did the math in an excel sheet, and got the same result (same scaling factors and same coordinates)

Comment: Then it seems likely the way you're using the information to crop the image is wrong. Sorry, I'm no `cv2` expert, but perhaps you should take a closer look at its documentation and/or see if you can find some example code somewhere.

Comment: `height, width = image.shape[0:2]` looks like the first dimension is height and second is width. Did you swap them in your slice? I got different numbers than you but the first dimension slice should be larger than the second.

Comment: When printing `print("H: {}, W: {}".format(height, width))`, I get: `H: 3508, W: 2479`, which seems correct?

Comment: Why is `imageWidth` less than `imageHeight` ? Your example picture wider than it is tall.  I think you've gotten your heighth/width, x/y mixed up.

Comment: @wwii That's just a cropping I did. The actual image is located here: https://imgur.com/fO2HS1O

Comment: What is `box`? And is its `'x','y','width','height'` designations the same?

Comment: Why do you have an actual image and a link to an original image in your question? Just the correct image would be better - we don't need two, thank you.